# How can I flatten this Future[T] structure?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

Given the following example:

```
  val handler : Connection = new DatabaseConnectionHandler()
  val result : Future[Future[Future[Option[ResultSet]]]] = handler.connect
    .map( (parameters) => handler )
    .map( connection => connection.sendQuery("BEGIN TRANSACTION SERIALIZABLE") )
    .map( future => future.map( query => query.rows ) )
    .map( future => handler.sendQuery("COMMIT").map( query => future ) )
```

Is it possible to flatten it to receive a `Future[Option[ResultSet]]` at the end instead of this future inside a future inside a future structure in Scala?

I am currently using Scala's 2.10 Future's and Promise's, but I can't find a way to to this. I know I can use nested callbacks but I would rather avoid that since the code is going to look horrible.

The `Connection` trait is defined [here](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-netty/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/mauricio/postgresql/Connection.scala).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Whenever you `map` with an argument of type `A => Future[B]` you should really be using `flatMap`.

The code would then be like this:

```
  val connection : Connection = new DatabaseConnectionHandler( DefaultConfiguration )
  val result: Future[QueryResult] = connection.connect
    .flatMap( _ => connection.sendQuery("BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ") )
    .flatMap( _ => connection.sendQuery("SELECT 0") )
    .flatMap( _ => connection.sendQuery("COMMIT").map( value => query ) )
```

Alternatively, you could use for-comprehension. [It uses `flatMap` for you](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html).

```
val connection : Connection = new DatabaseConnectionHandler( DefaultConfiguration )
val result: Future[QueryResult] = for {
  _ <- connection.connect
  _ <- connection.sendQuery("BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ")
  _ <- connection.sendQuery("SELECT 0")
  queryResult <- connection.sendQuery("COMMIT").map( value => query )
} yield { queryResult }
```

Comment: There is no `flatten` in `scala.concurrent.Future`

Comment: @senz Yes, `scala.concurrent.Future` don't have `flatten`. But you can use `f flatMap identity`. [See here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/yVYe_xnUOFA)

Comment: Are you mixing options and futures in your for-comprehension?  Isn't that not allowed?

Answer (score 9):

You should use a `flatMap` instead of a `map` here.

The `flatMap` expects a function `fun` returning a future `g` and returns the future `h` holding the value from the future `g` that `fun` returned.

Also, consider writing this within a `for`-comprehension, see how [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).