# Converting a Future[Future[(String,String)]] to Future[(String,String)] in Scala using for comprehension

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I've a `Future[Future[(String,String)]]` and I want to convert it into a `Future[(String,String)]` using a for comprehension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I flatten this Future\[T\] structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835222/how-can-i-flatten-this-futuret-structure)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily with a for comprehension, a simple approach involves the use of `flatMap` over `identity`.

Consider for instance

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f: Future[Future[(String,String)]] = Future { Future {("a","aa")} }
```

Then

```
f.flatMap(identity)
res: scala.concurrent.Future[(String, String)] = Promise$DefaultPromise@1849937
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val futureOfFutures: Future[Future[(String,String)]] = Future { Future {("a","aa")} }
for(futureOfFuture <- futureOfFutures; futureResult <- futureOfFuture) yield futureResult
```

Just in case you wanted to use for comprehension. This is how you do it.